# Не работают привязки к свойству Visible

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Делаю вот такие привязки:

```
cbSaveResultMode.DataBindings.Add(nameof(ComboBox.SelectedItem), _configViewModel, nameof(_configViewModel.ImageSaveMode), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
gbRelativeWithStructureOptions.DataBindings.Add(nameof(GroupBox.Visible), _configViewModel, nameof(_configViewModel.SaveStructureVisability), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
gbRelativeWithoutStructureOptions.DataBindings.Add(nameof(GroupBox.Visible), _configViewModel, nameof(_configViewModel.WithoutSaveStructureVisability), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
gbPathAlreadyCreatedOptions.DataBindings.Add(nameof(GroupBox.Visible), _configViewModel, nameof(_configViewModel.PathAlreadyCreateVisability), false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

ViewModel выглядит так:

```
   public class ConfigViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
             public ImageSaveMode ImageSaveMode
        {
            get => _config.ImageSaveMode;
            set
            {
                ToggleVisability(_config.ImageSaveMode);
                _config.ImageSaveMode = value;
                ToggleVisability(_config.ImageSaveMode);
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SaveStructureVisability));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(WithoutSaveStructureVisability));
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PathAlreadyCreateVisability));
            }
        }
        public bool SaveStructureVisability
        {
            get => _visabilityDict[ImageSaveMode.SaveStructure];
            set { _visabilityDict[ImageSaveMode.SaveStructure] = value; }
        }
        public bool WithoutSaveStructureVisability
        {
            get => _visabilityDict[ImageSaveMode.WithoutSaveStructure];
            set
            {
                _visabilityDict[ImageSaveMode.WithoutSaveStructure] = value;
            }
        }
        public bool PathAlreadyCreateVisability
        {
            get => _visabilityDict[ImageSaveMode.PathAlreadyCreate];
            set
            {
                _visabilityDict[ImageSaveMode.PathAlreadyCreate] = value;
            }
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
   }
```

Хочу, чтобы при переключении значения в ComboBox, менялась видимость групп на форме, но ничего не происходит... Хотя OnPropertyChanged я дергаю.

Answer (score 2):

Хм...
Оказывается, что если установить в редакторе значение видимость форм в руками false, то привязки не работают и не реагируют на то, что значения меняются на true.

Comment: Как-то так всегда работало, да.